# Show the correct number of registrations that are incomplete instead of the static value 1

Tags: php, laravel

I have the index() method of the UserController that returns the past and next registrations of the user in conferences:

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request){
        $pageLimit = 5;
        $user = $request->user();

        $pastRegistrations = $user->registrations()->with(['conference' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('end_date', '<', now());
        }])->paginate($pageLimit);

        $nextRegistrations = $user->registrations()->with(['conference' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('end_date', '>', now());
        }])->paginate($pageLimit);

        return view('users.index',
            compact('user', 'pastRegistrations','nextRegistrations'));
    }
 }
```

Then in the view to show the registrations is used a foreach like below. And it appears the link "Pay" only for the registrations done by the user that have not yet been paid, that is, the column "status" in "registrations" table is "I" ("I" mean registration incomplete). And it's working.

But I also have a message "You have 1 registration in a conference(s) incomplete, please make the payment to complete your registration." that, for now, is showing the static value 1.

Do you know how to properly show the correct number of registrations that are incomplete instead of the static value 1? Is necessary to do another query or is possible to reuse the code in the index() to achieve that?

```
    <span>You have 1 registration in a conference(s) inmcomplete, please make the payment to complete your registration.</span>

    <ul>    
       <li>                      
    // show next registrations
    @foreach($nextRegistrations as $nextRegistration)
         <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
            <i class="material-icons">info</i>
            <span>You have 1 registration in a conference waiting for payment.</span>
        </div>
        @if(!empty($nextRegistration->conference || !empty($nextRegistration->conference->start_date)))
            <li class="list-group-item">
                <h5>{{optional($nextRegistration->conference)->name}}</h5>
                 @if ($nextRegistration->status === 'I')
                        <a href="{{route('conferences.payment',
                            ['id' => $nextRegistration->conference->id,
                            'slug' => $nextRegistration->conference->slug,
                            'regID'=> $nextRegistration->id])}}"
                            class="btn btn-primary ml-2"><i
                            class="fa fa-usd"></i> Pay  
                        </a>
                @endif
            </li>
        @endif
    @endforeach
   </li>
</ul>
<div class="text-center d-flex justify-content-center mt-3">
      {{$nextRegistrations->fragment('nextConferences')->links("pagination::bootstrap-4")}}
</div>
```

Comment: where is the status field ? in registration table ?

Comment: Yes, is a field of the registrations table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like this

```
            $pastRegistrations = $user->registrations()->with(['conference' => function ($query) {
                $query->where('end_date', '<', now());
            }]);

            $nextRegistrations = $user->registrations()->with(['conference' => function ($query) {
                $query->where('end_date', '>', now());
            }]);
            $pastRegistrationCount = $pastRegistrations->where('status' , 1 )->count();
            $nextRegistrationCount = $nextRegistrations->where('status' , 1 )->count();
            $totalCount = $nextRegistrationCount + $pastRegistrationCount ;
            $pastRegistrations = $pastRegistrations-->paginate($pageLimit);
            $nextRegistrations = $nextRegistrations-->paginate($pageLimit);
            return view('users.index',
            compact('user', 'pastRegistrations','nextRegistrations' , 'totalCount'));
```

Comment: Thanks, the pastRegistrations the status already has to be "C" (complete). So maybe is only necessary the "            $nextRegistrationCount = $nextRegistrations->where('status' , 1 )->count();
"? But the status should be like where('status', 'I')?

Comment: Thanks, but with "$nextRegistrations = $user->registrations()->with(['conference' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('end_date', '>', now());
        }])->paginate($pageLimit);


        $IncompleteRegistrations = $nextRegistrations->where('status' , 'I' )->count();". Then in the view with "        <span>You have {{IncompleteRegistrations}} registration in a conference waiting for payment.</span>
" the message appears in each pagination result with a different value for each page.

Comment: For example in the first page appears   "<span>You have 2 registration in a conference waiting for payment.</span>", if the user is in the page 2 it appears "  <span>You have 1 registration in a conference waiting for payment.</span>". Do you know how to have only a message that shows the total of all incomplete registrations in all pages?

Comment: you should count before pagination like I did

Comment: Thanks, but like that it appears "Method paginate does not exist.
".

Comment: there should be 2 different variables , you cant use the same variable which have count() to paginate too

Comment: Thanks, with " $nextRegistrations = $user->registrations()->with(['conference' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('end_date', '>', now());
        }]);


        $IncRegistrations = $nextRegistrations->where('status' , 'I' )->count();

        $nextRegistrations = $nextRegistrations->paginate($pageLimit);"

Comment: it appears "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::fragment() ". I have after the foreach this "<div class="text-center d-flex justify-content-center mt-3">
 {{$nextRegistrations->fragment('nextConferences')->links("pagination::bootstrap-4")}}  </div>".

Comment: I udpated the question with the "<div class="text-center d-flex justify-content-center mt-3">
      {{$nextRegistrations->fragment('nextConferences')->links("pagination::bootstrap-4")}}
</div>".